# CSS Transition Questions

Tags: css, google-chrome, transition

I've got 2 questions (and I'm pretty novice, so be gentle please). The questions are related to this [jsfiddle](http:////jsfiddle.net/dmperkins74/hpm6wzuh/).

1. On the sample url below, why aren't my transitions working at all on chrome. I thought webkit was what I needed for chrome!
2. Is there an easier way to override a transition? I'm currently adding a mouseDown specifically just so I can nix the transition, but it feels clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transition` property is now fully supported by all major browsers for a while, so -webkit- is no longer needed (http://caniuse.com/#search=transition)

For your issue, just change

```
transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out 0;
```

to

```
transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out;
```

I know it seems weird, but since a delay of 0s is not recognized, the browsers assume that 0 is a new duration time, and override the 0.4s duration that was set before, resulting in a 0s transition.

Comment: Most excellent, thanks a bunch! I have so much to learn. And so happy to just use transition, my main code has all of the -moz -o -ms stuff in it, it's ugly. I have to get in the habit of checking caniuse i suppose!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Syntax for transition in the JavaScript was wrong.

This is the correct way :)

```
testDiv.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "top .3s linear");
```

```js
testDiv.style.top = "100px";


theBtn.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  btnUpFunc();
}, false)

theBtn.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  btnDownFunc();
}, false)


function btnDownFunc() {
  testDiv.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "none");
  testDiv.style.top = "50px";
}

function btnUpFunc() {
  testDiv.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "top .3s linear");
  testDiv.style.top = "100px";
}
```

```css
#testDiv {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out 0;
}
#theBtn {
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv">Hello World</div>
<button id="theBtn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense for sure. However, why won't it do the initial slide down in chrome like it does in firefox. In FF, the second the page loads, the div slides down because I've to a transition in the CSS and I adjust the top for that div immediately in the JS. Works on FF, but not Chrome :-\

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the below lines

```
testDiv.style.webkitTransition = "none";
testDiv.style.webkitTransition = "top 0.4s ease-in-out 0";
```

And remove the delay value (or change it to `0s`), then works properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/hpm6wzuh/5/